# Veracode reports XSS issue in XMLHttpResponse Javascript

Tags: javascript, jsp, xss

I have Struts 2.x web application. In this application, I am using `XMLHttpRequest` for refreshing a div with a table. I have a separate JSP page for rendering the HTML table. I get the JSP page response in `XMLHttpRequest` and update the response to div. Veracode is showing XSS issue on `innerHTML` line of code. How can I sanitize the HTML content here?

```
function ajaxFileUploadRefresh(){
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else{// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
        document.getElementById("StatusDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText; // Refreshing the Div with response. This is where Veracode shows error.
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("POST","StrutsAction_methodName",true); // This action will be redirected to jsp
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send(postString);   
}
```

Comment: "How can I sanitize the HTML content here?" — Why does it need to be sanitized? Is the URL `StrutsAction_methodName` not trustworthy? It appears to be part of the same site!

Comment: Thanks @Quentin. Probably I shouldn't have used Sanitize here. But the veracode tool is showing me XSS issue when the response is added to the div.

Comment: Tools to detect security holes tend to be stupid. They detect potential problems. You absolutely must analyse their reports to see if there is an actual problem and not trust them blindly.

Comment: You may be true here @Quentin. I am exploring in that direction as well. To put this as a false positive.

Answer (score 1):

If the JSP page is producing HTML output, then what you have is fine. As long as the JSP itself produces correct HTML, then there is no issue.

If the response were text instead, then you should use `innerText` instead of `innerHTML`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @fgb for the reply. Yes, JSP will be producing the HTML output. It is not a text. It is HTML. So I have to use `innerHTML`. But Veracode tool is showing this as a security flaw. I am concerned with that.